# Free hard drive partitioning tool for Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Partition Manager for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/13943/best-partition-manager-for-windows)

I'm looking for free software for Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit that can partition a hard drive. In my country (Bangladesh) a power outage is a normal event, so I want to ensure the software won't cause any loss of data even during a power outage.

Any recommendations?

**EDIT (answers to the comments)**

I was used to use Paragon Partition Manager for Windows 7 32 bit. It is a pretty good software. Once there was power outage while it was resizing a drive. After power was back, it was able to continue its work from the last state and no data was lost! I'm not sure if it was just pure luck.

Recently I've moved to Windows 7 64 bit and that version of Partition Manager no longer works. Also, Paragon wasn't free. So I'm looking for a free good alternative.

I know exactly what I'm looking for. I need to resize two of my logical drives. I don't need any software like CloneZilla or similar type.

I have an UPS which can provide power back up for 30 minutes. But when power goes out, it comes back after 1 hour typically.

Comment: If your power goes out, it doesn't matter what partition data is on if your HDD gets fried

Comment: Can you please edit your question to better explain what you want, or think you want or need? Disk partitioning is easy, and tools are available, but probably aren't what you want to do.

Comment: I think the problem is with the new laptop or desktop is familiar as Microsoft providing only one partition with windows installation so user can't save their data on other drive.

Comment: Agree with Joe Internet, you are probably looking for a cloning software like Clonezilla to copy data to a second drive. If it is on the same drive, two partitions will not save you.

Comment: A UPS would be much more effective to prevent data loss in case of power outage, and they're pretty cheap these days. This is not an answer, just a friendly opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Easeus](http://www.easeus.com/download.htm) it is available freeware and trial version. In my case I used free version and its working fine.

Comment: +1 IMO, this is easily the best free tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

[MiniTool](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) is a free alternative for home solutions...

MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition is a free partition manager software designed by MiniTool Solution Ltd. Our partition manager supports 32/64 bit Windows Operating System including Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7.

Home users can perform complicated partition operations by using this powerful yet free partition manager to manage their hard disk. Functions include: Resizing partitions, Copying partitions, Create partition, Delete partition, Format partition, Convert partition, Explore partition, Hide partition, Change drive letter, Set active partition, Partition Recovery.

MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition is designated for home user only, to use MiniTool Partition Wizard in a business environment, MiniTool Partition Wizard Professional Edition is required.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 in disk management you have all tools you need to partition drivers, eaven to resize them.

Tell us what are your purpose of partitionig?

Power loss - better UPS, backups, low energy procesors, power save modes ets